# how to style Reddit subgroup to work with RTL languages?

Tags: css, stylesheet, right-to-left, flip, reddit

I want to open a subbreddit in hebrew and i want to "mirror" the site using the css sytlesheet so it will fit nicely with the hebrew. I want that the tree structure of the comments will be aligned to the right. 
here is an example of what i want to achieve:
before:
[image1](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=11141839092711)
after (with damaged text):
[image2](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=014183902452)

so, i want to make the structure of the site to look like in image2, but without damaging the text.
is it possible?

**update:** 
here is the css code that i have right now:
there could be non-relevant selections, i'm just experimenting withe the stylesheet by trial and error:

```
    .thing {
display: inline;
}

.sitetable {
display: inline;
}

div.content {
display: block;
float: right;
}

body {
direction: rtl;
}

.midcol.likes {
float: right;
}
```

**Update2: solved!**
i added this line and it fix it:

```
.child {
padding-right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: This would be better with a question about roadblocks you have hit. It's probably possible to move the major page pieces around, but may be trickier to reorder things where the order is a result of content flowing.

Comment: I was able to reach quite far to achieve the effect that i want, but i just can't handle the mirroring of the tree-structure of the comments. I actually don't have a clue how to invert the tree...maybe it's impossible.. i don't know..
its seems like the only way to do it is to somehow invert the padding..

Comment: I'm working with the inspector tool to find what makes the actual padding of the "child" but i don't find anything to play with..

Comment: Then show us what you've got, and the parts which are giving you trouble. Provide a full minimal working example.

Comment: i tried to edit the main post but i can't add more link so i put them here:
1. http://www.imagesup.net/?di=514183915439  , and 2: http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1514183918779 , so you can see that the problem is not with the arrows (if you look closely at the left of the image you can still see the padding lines).

Comment: You definitely can edit the main post. When I say "minimal working example", I mean code, not screenshots.

Comment: i updated the post to include the css sheet the i got so far. btw, why people are down-voting this? what the hell is wrong with this question? i just thought that maybe someone  has  experienced in styling reddit and could possibly know how to invert the tree...don't see anything wrong.

Comment: You're getting downvotes because of the lack of code. This would be even better with enough html to make a minimal working example of your problem. Maybe use a fiddle site to show the problem, as well.

Comment: there is no code...its reddit, i'm playing only with the css. but never mind, i fixed the tree. it was such a simple fix i can't believe it took me so much time! thank you for trying!

Comment: Reddit is made of html, like the rest of the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved! i added this line and it fix it:

```
.child {
padding-right: 25px;
}
```